# Parse data export file size

Tags: parse-platform

If I have millions of rows data in Parse, would the data export give me a huge json file or a set of smaller json files? I would prefer multiple smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

According to [This official blog post](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/one-click-export/) they just send you a link to **one file** which contains your entire data via email.

As the blog says:

> Go to your app’s settings page and click export. After a few minutes
>   we’ll send you an email with a link to **a file that contains all of
>   your data stored in Parse**. The format is identical to the one returned
>   by the REST API so there’s no need to write extra parsing code.

Example:

```
ilair:export ilya$ unzip export.zip
Archive:  export.zip
 extracting: Foo.json                
 extracting: LocationUpdate.json     
 extracting: StackObject.json        
 extracting: Temp.json               
 extracting: TestObject.json         
 extracting: TestObject2.json        
  inflating: Thing.json              
 extracting: _User.json              
ilair:export ilya$ cat Thing.json
{ "results": [
{
  "name": "plate",
  "createdAt": "2012-03-08T23:36:14.832Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-03-09T22:04:08.937Z",
  "objectId": "7xS50cVZ2O"
},
{
  "name": "knife",
  "createdAt": "2012-03-08T23:36:20.233Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-03-09T22:04:05.686Z",
  "objectId": "NyCyWue7wu"
},
{
  "name": "fork",
  "createdAt": "2012-03-08T23:36:24.239Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-03-09T22:04:03.851Z",
  "objectId": "fywEg7EHav"
},
{
  "name": "cup",
  "createdAt": "2012-03-09T22:04:01.259Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-03-09T22:04:01.259Z",
  "objectId": "WU2KkJaNmK"
}
] }
```

Comment: @Edmond I have exported a few thousand records holding DB and All I got was one file. Never tried it with millions. From what we know from Parse docs, they maintain they will send one file. You can take this up on their QA forum to get an official response on that.